# Which library is better for image processing, GD2 or ImageMagick?

Tags: 7, media

Is ImageMagick is supported by Drupal 7? If the answer is positive, which is better for image processing, between GD2 and ImageMagick?

Are any other alternatives for Drupal 7?

Comment: The part about the better library is rather subjective; what is better for somebody could not be the better choice for somebody else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This depends on how many images you will be making on the fly and how many you will have cached.

100% true sweeping statement backed up by no cited sources: "The internet is all about speed."

If you are taking twice as long to render in Imagemagick then you are going against 'The Internet is all about speed'. But yoursite may not have lots of fresh big images getting themselves perpetually updated all the time, in which case use ImageMagick with some caching.

Answer (score 6):

Drupal 7 supports ImageMagick with the [ImageMagick module](http://drupal.org/project/imagemagick)

I suspect better is subjective depending on your specific image manipulation tasks. The benchmarks I could find didn't conclusively favor either one overall but specific tasks were faster in one or the other. Opinion favors ImageMagick for quality but recent posts suggests GD2 has caught up.